# Why the foreground process of Notepad created by subprocess.Popen() could not be terminated?

Tags: python, subprocess

I wanted to use the python program below that subprocess.Popen() is called to run notepad, wait 3 seconds, and hoped to kill the notepad foreground window.

```
import time
import win32gui
import win32process
import subprocess

notepad_process = subprocess.Popen(['notepad.exe'], shell=False)
time.sleep(3)

_, foreground_pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
print('foreground_pid={}'.format(foreground_pid))
print('notepad_process.pid={}'.format(notepad_process.pid))

notepad_process.terminate() # there are TWO Notepad process if commented this line
```

I run it on my Windows 11, however, the Notepad foreground windowo is still there.
The foreground pid and the notepad_process.pid I printed is not the same as I hoped.

I notice that there is more than just one instance of "Notepad.exe" process if I do not terminate the process as the last line is commented. Actually, I find two "Notepad.exe" process, and finally find the foreground Notepad.exe process is the child process of the other one.

BTW, I successfully terminate the Notepad process when run it on another Windows 10 computer.
BTW2, I also successfully terminate the process when I change notepad.exe to mspaint.exe whenever on Windows 10 or Windows 11.

Can you tell me why the foreground cannot be terminated? or help me to find the appropriate method to find the PID(process id) of the foreground Notepad.exe?

Not to just terminate the process, as I find that "taskkill /t /pid xxx" is useful to kill the process and its child processes by pid.